# C# Calling an azure function http trigger from azure function timer trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I already have an HTTP trigger function that I have published in Azure. I want to run the HTTP trigger on daily basis. So I thought I would create another timer trigger to call the HTTP trigger. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to have an http trigger function?
If the idea is to trigger a function on a daily basis, simply use a time trigger function and set the cron accordingly.

Comment: You are having a HTTP trigger function already, do you have client programs that use that already? If yes, then you need to have this another timer function that runs daily and can call that http trigger function - no harm in that. The timer triggered function may/could be running on a different host than your http trigger function, so make no assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, and please excuse the delay in replying; I automated it using the Timmer trigger function.